# How can to make UITableView cell boarders reach all the way to the edge of the screen on the left side?

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, uitableview

How can I make cell boarders in UITableView reach all the way to the edge of the screen on the left side?

[image]

Comment: Are you using auto layout? Maybe you have the constraints defined to the margin

Answer (score 0):

Just set this properties to your table view:

```
[tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
[tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

And add set this property to your cell:

```
[cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

Answer (score 0):

> This piece of could will solve your problem. write this function in your class where you are using tableview.

```
    -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [self.tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```